# How to remove drawing with gpu module in blender?

Tags: python, gpu-module

I have drawn some points with the GPU module of Blender and I need to draw other things in an empty window without closing Blender. But I don't know how to remove all these points with codes. It seems all these points are not showing in Outliner (which means they are not objects) so that I cannot manipulate them. So I want to overcome mainly two problems:

1. How to remove or clear these points with codes without closing Blender?
2. How to manipulate these points like other objects in Blender?

[image]

Comment: afaik, you can't for both questions. For the first one, only way is to keep the handler obtained when added it so that you can remove it later. For the second one, this is drawing only and does not create geometry.

Comment: Though, if you were able to create this using the gpu module, certainly you can do it too using Python and for instance mesh api https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Mesh.html#bpy.types.Mesh.from_pydata